# how can I write a query in mySQL which shows the average trips in a day?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of IDs and the detail of the trips they've taken. I want to see how many trips each ID takes in a day on average but I don't know how to write this query. The data I have in my table is something like this:

| ID | Ride_id | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2022-3-4 |
| 1 | 124 | 2022-3-4 |
| 1 | 111 | 2021-2-8 |
| 2 | 584 | 2019-4-18 |
| 2 | 256 | 2019-4-18 |
| 2 | 805 | 2020-5-8 |
| 2 | 127 | 2020-5-8 |
| 2 | 457 | 2020-5-8 |
| 3 | 100 | 2021-4-7 |
| 3 | 101 | 2021-4-7 |
| 3 | 202 | 2021-5-17 |
| 3 | 741 | 2021-5-17 |

So basically, the average rides ID=1 takes is 1.5 and the average rides ID=2 takes is 2.5 and so on. I need a query to calculate and show the result like this:

| ID | Average_of_daily_trips |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 2.5 |
| 3 | 2 |

My current query uses only one condition: WHERE ID in ()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First count the trips on each day for each id, then make the average over those counts.

```
select id, avg(trips)
from (select id, count(*) as trips
      from trips
      -- where id in(1,2,3)
      group by id, date) t
group by id
```

If you need to, you can uncomment the `where` clause in the subquery to filter for particular ids ...